# How to add custom component ngFormBuilder Form.io

Tags: angularjs, formbuilder, formio

i try  add custom component to ngFormBuilder, but i can not find success
I am using angularjs 
This example https://github.com/formio/ngFormBuilder not working for me

I find this issue https://github.com/formio/ngFormBuilder/issues/135
 but not working correct, all form clear when i run this code

Please help me in this problem, Thanks

Comment: why you vote bad ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you share your attempts and a clear description of the error?

Comment: "Not working" i mean my component not show in other components, and not show error. maybe you can help me find example ?

Answer (score 0):

Your given description is very short to know what is your exact problem ? Can you give some code example? 
Anyways,I am providing you a small 'way to go' example.
This is defining your angular app.

```
 var app = angular.module('formioApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.select', 'formio', 'ngFormBuilder', 'ngJsonExplorer', 'ngFileUpload']);
```

This is schema for from.You can customise this as your needs.

```
  var formSchemaJSON = { "components": [{ "input": true, "tableView": true, "inputType": "text", "inputMask": "", "label": "Name", "key": "name", "placeholder": "", "prefix": "", "suffix": "", "multiple": false, "defaultValue": "", "protected": false, "unique": false, "persistent": true, "validate": { "required": false, "minLength": "", "maxLength": "", "pattern": "", "custom": "", "customPrivate": false }, "conditional": { "show": "", "when": null, "eq": "" }, "type": "textfield", "tags": [] }, { "input": true, "label": "Submit", "tableView": false, "key": "submit1", "size": "md", "leftIcon": "", "rightIcon": "", "block": false, "action": "submit", "disableOnInvalid": false, "theme": "primary", "type": "button", "tags": [], "conditional": { "show": "", "when": null, "eq": "" } }], "display": "form", "page": 0, "numPages": 1 };
```

This is your angular controller

```
 app.controller('formioAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', 'Upload', '$compile', 'formioComponents', '$timeout', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope, Upload, $compile, formioComponents, $timeout) {
    $rootScope.form = formSchemaJSON;
```

Now you have to put this in html page where you want your form builder to show up in

```
<form-builder form="form" options="{ noSubmit: true }"></form-builder>
```

now if you want to add a custom component ,you better create a new js file and add them in a new group,like this and register the component.

```
 app.config(['formioComponentsProvider', function (formioComponentsProvider) {

        formioComponentsProvider.addGroup('amazing', { title: 'Custom Template Components' });
    formioComponentsProvider.register('todaysDate', {
            title: 'Date Fields',
            //template: 'formio/components/todaysDate/todaysDate.html',
            template: 'formio/components/todaysDate.html',
            controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                $scope.setValue = function (value) {
                    $scope.data[$scope.component.key] = value;
                };
            }],

            group: 'amazing',
            icon: 'fa fa-calendar',
            settings: {
                input: true,
                label: '',
                tableView: true,
                key: 'todaysDate',
                // key:'columns',
                size: 'md',
                leftIcon: '',
                rightIcon: '',
                block: false,
                //action: 'submit',
                disableOnInvalid: false,
                theme: 'primary',
                type: 'todaysDate',
                dataSource: "",
                columns: [{
                    components: [{ "input": true, "tableView": true, "inputType": "text", "inputMask": "", "label": "", "key": "todaysDate", "dataSource": "", "placeholder": "", "prefix": "", "suffix": "", "multiple": true, "defaultValue": "", "protected": false, "unique": false, "persistent": true, "validate": { "required": false, "minLength": "", "maxLength": "", "pattern": "", "custom": "", "customPrivate": false }, "conditional": { "show": "", "when": null, "eq": "" }, "type": "textfield", "tags": [] }]
                }

                ],
                validate: {
                    required: false,
                    multiple: '',
                    custom: ''
                },
                conditional: {
                    show: null,
                    when: null,
                    eq: ''
                }


            },
            controller: ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
                var settings = $scope.component;
                //settings.hideLabel = true;
            }],
            views: [
                {
                    name: 'Display',
                    template: 'formio/components/todaysDate/DateFieldDisplay.html'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Validation',
                    template: 'formio/components/todaysDate/validate.html'
                }
            ]
        });
}






app.run([
              '$templateCache',
              'FormioUtils',
              function ($templateCache, FormioUtils) {
     $templateCache.put('formio/components/todaysDate.html', FormioUtils.fieldWrap('<div id ="todaysDateDirective" class ="todaysDateDirective" todays-Date></div>'));

    }
```

and now your directive

```
app.directive('todaysDate', function ($rootScope, $compile) {
return {
link:
controller:
template:

}

});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can i add ng-if, ng-model,validation in this input ?